# scraping table using beautiful soup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the address/amount/share columns of the top 100 holders on this website: https://cryptorank.io/price/butterflydao/holders

This is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

projects = ["butterflydao", "convex-finance", "dopex"]

urls = []
for i in projects:
    url = "https://cryptorank.io/price/" + i + "/holders"
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    
    div = soup.find_all('div')
    print(div) # has no table info even though all tables are within divs

    table1 = div.find_all('table') # returns None
    print(table1)
```

When I use beautifulsoup I cannot find any table elements using find_all(). When I look at the div class elements, no table information or data shows up either.

Any suggestions on how I should approach this?

Answer (score 1):

To get table head use this and sore in variable thead, which contains all the table header name.

```
thead = [i.text for i in soup.find_all('th')]
thead = thead[:3]
```

Then to extract each Address and Amount and share use this.

```
tbody = []
for r in soup.select('table')[0].tbody.find_all('tr'):
    tbody.append([i.text.strip() for i in r.find_all('td')])

stud = "https://cryptorank.io/price/{}/holders"
for i in projects:
    stud.format(i) ## this will open pages
```

tbody will contain all the Address, amount and Share. enjoy!

Comment: Hi, my issues is that beautifulsoup does not find the table. Therefore there is no 'th' or 'td' elements to retrieve

Comment: url = "https://cryptorank.io/price/{}/holders"     url.format(i)    This will work

Comment: Use selenium webdriver instead. if still not working.

Answer (score 1):

To get all data, you can use their API via `requests`. For example:

```py
import json
import requests


url = "https://api.cryptorank.io/v0/coins/butterflydao/holders"
data = requests.get(url).json()

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

total = data["data"]["tokenStat"]["circulating_supply"]

for holder in data["data"]["holders"]:
    print(
        "{:<45} {:<10.2f} {:<10}".format(
            holder["address"],
            holder["balance"],
            "{:.2f} %".format((holder["balance"] / total) * 100),
        )
    )
```

Prints:

```
0xbde4dfb0dbb0dd8833efb6c5bd0ce048c852c487    499859.55  90.61 %   
0xe9ab8038ee6dd4fcc7612997fe28d4e22019c4b4    18245.55   3.31 %    
0xf43b15ab692fde1f9c24a9fce700adcc809d5391    14298.69   2.59 %    
0xa52fd396891e7a74b641a2cb1a6999fcf56b077e    5755.34    1.04 %    
0xaba85673458b876c911ccff5e3711bcedb3b4f56    2945.48    0.53 %    
0x3496681ef5e8ebbf01eeeebae10084343d65dbea    1530.40    0.28 %    
0xdf9ab3c649005ebfdf682d2302ca1f673e0d37a2    1079.65    0.20 %    
0xbd1f20fbbe9e860e055a1e3355c5ffec2c92c7ea    920.14     0.17 %    

...and so on.
```